Prove that the following limit is $1/2$
Let $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+x_n^{1/x_n}$$
Prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-n}{(\log(x_n))^n}=1/2$$
I tried using Stolz-Cesaro because the numerator will be $x_{n+1}-x_n-1$, which is $e^{\log(x_n)/x_n}-1$, and $\log(x_n)/x_n \to 0$ as $x_n \to \infty$, but the denominator looks terrible and I don't know how to further proceed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

is the denominator correct? Since $x_n$ is close to $n$, $(\log x_n)^n$ is huge, and you want rather a slowly increasing thing.

If the exercise is correct, then yes, it is $(\log x_n)^n$ indeed. If not, well...

the correct denominator seems to be $(\log x_n)^2$

Well, if with this modification you get the result, then you are clearly right, and $(\log x_n)^n$ is too huge. I will try to check this out, but you can write an answer if you want.

I don't have an answer, it is based on computer experiments :)

Ok, I managed to solve it using Stolz-Cesaro, and you we right indeed. Thank you so much, this problem is killing me since yesterday, and it was wrong all along.
